# flatten table into summary report with details in SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting, summary

Is it possible to flatten out a database table for a report using sql (mysql).  I can do with with php but it would be nice if I could do it simpler in sql.

example:

1) input: raw data - one line per cust/start & end time

```
cust   start   end
8000   0900    1000
8000   1000    1100
8000   1200    1300
9000   0900    1000
9000   1000    1100
```

2) required output: data flattened out - one line per customer with all start & end times following on same line

```
cust  all related start-end times
----  ------------------------------
8000  0900-1000 1000-1100 1200-1300
9000  0900-1000 1000-1100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
select cust, group_concat(concat(start,'-',end) SEPARATOR ' ')
from mytable
group by cust
```

See the [working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b768b/11).

Comment: very nice! I've never seen that syntax before. Does it exist on other platforms?

Comment: Well, each platform has its own way of doing it, but any decent platform should allow you to get such a result

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query has to have a fixed number of columns.  This poses a problem in your case, because you don't know how many columns you need.

One workaround is to put all the results in one column.  This produces a result like '090-1000,1000-1100,1200-1300'.  You can do this with `group_concat()`:

```
select cust,
       group_concat(concat(start, '-', end) separator ', ' order by start) as StartEnds
from t
group by cust
```